# How can I change to create table successfully?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error message when I run this code on MY SQL:

```
create table productlines(
productLine VARCHAR(50),
textDescription VARCHAR(4000),
htmlDescription MEDIUMTEXT,
image MEDIUMBLOB
)
```

And I receive a response that:

> 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'productLine VARCHAR(50), textDescription VARCHAR(4000), htmlDescription MEDIUMTE' at line 1'

How can I fix this code?

Comment: There's something before the line `productLine VARCHAR(50)` that you're not showing here. https://dbfiddle.uk/wjpfFRJA

Comment: Or possibly before "CREATE"?

Comment: copy this text into notepad. Then copy from the notepad and paste into the code editor. Highlight and run